# exponential function of of big O

Tags: asymptotics

Can someone please help me solve the following?

$$f=exp\{\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\} = exp\{\frac{a+x+O(x^2)}{b+x+O(x^2)}\} = exp\{\frac{a+x}{b+x}+O(x^2)\}=exp\{\frac{a+x}{b+x}\}+O(?)$$

For the nominator $O(x^2) $ as $n\rightarrow0$

For the denominator $O(x^2) $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Also is there any good text concerning functions of the big O?

Comment: Are you considering $\lim x \to \infty$ or $\lim x \to 0$?

Comment: Both since it’s originally a uniform approximation. Thanks